# How to create rosbag file using usb camera provide camera images as sensor_msgs/CompressedImage and odometry as nav_msgs/Odometry

Tags: ros, usb-camera, rosbag

Help me to create rosbag file using usb camera which provide camera images as sensor_msgs/CompressedImage and odometry as nav_msgs/Odometry.

Answer (score 0):

You can try [this](http://wiki.ros.org/usb_cam) package for usb camera.If you want to use cv_bridge to publish the camera data to a topic use [this link](http://wiki.ros.org/cv_bridge/Tutorials/ConvertingBetweenROSImagesAndOpenCVImagesPython).

for example if you have published the data in `/camera/data` topic

you can record the rosbag using following command

```
rosbag record /camera/data
```